# How do I attach HTML in email body using python

Tags: python, html, email, outlook

I am automating mails using python and it's working fine. The problem arises when I try to add html into the email body. The HTML code is added as an attachment in the outlook mail instead of embedding it in the body. How do I overcome this ?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
import smtplib
import sys


recipients = ['abc@emaxple.com','def@example.com'] 
emaillist = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in recipients]
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = str("Trial")
msg['From'] = 'abc@example.com'

msg.preamble = 'Multipart massage.\n'

html="""<html><body><p>Hi!</p>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</body></html>"""

part2=MIMEText(html,'html') 

part = MIMEText("Hello")

msg.attach(part)
msg.attach(part2)

for excel_file_location in sys.argv[1].split(","):
    part = MIMEApplication(open(str(excel_file_location),"rb").read())
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=str(excel_file_location.split("\\")[-1]))
    msg.attach(part)


server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("abc@example.com", "asdgfasgas")

server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code, have you tried viewing the email on something different than outlook, for example gmail? To make sure its not an issue with outlook specifically

Comment: It works the same way even if I check from outlook website. And since I am working on this within my company, everybody who would receive this mail only on outlook.

Comment: The point is to first understand if the issue is from outlook or your code, so you can direct your debugging efforts in the right direction. Try sending to a gmail and tell if it persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message needs to be of type multipart/alternative. The default multipart subtype is "mixed".
Try this:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
```